# How to pass string and component as prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I can pass something like this fine:

```
<CardTitle title={this.props.post.title} subtitle={
    <Link to={this.props.post.author}>{this.props.post.author}</Link>
} />
```

But I need to pass both a component and some string text, but doing this doesn't work:

```
<CardTitle title={this.props.post.title} subtitle={(`
    This is a link: ${<Link to={this.props.post.author}>{this.props.post.author}</Link>}
`)} />
```

What's the right syntax for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try passing it as a React Element altogether, not as a string:

```babel
<CardTitle
  title={this.props.post.title}
  subtitle={
    <span>
      This is a link: <Link to={this.props.post.author}>{this.props.post.author}</Link>
    </span>
  }
/>
```

Then should be able to render `subtitle` as is. If you're using React >16, you might want to use [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) for this:

```babel
import { Fragment } from 'react';

// ...

subtitle={
  <Fragment>
    This is a link: <Link to={this.props.post.author}>{this.props.post.author}</Link>
  </Fragment>
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I had tried the first method but it resulted in an error because I didn't include a container tag (span in your case). Adding one works. Thanks.